# How to tell the ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker element to show the calendar?

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I am using the datetimepicker from 'ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker' which is working well.  But I have another control and would to open the calendar when the other control is clicked.

I have tried several things, and the latest:

```
export class Item {
   @ViewChild('datetimepicker') datetimepickerElement: ElementRef;

   ...

   public showDate() {
    let event = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true});
    this.datetimepickerElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
   }

   public getDueDate(): moment {
     return ...
   }

}
```

where the relevant html fragment is:

```
     <input #datetimepicker
         type='text'
         class="form-control"
         a2e-datetimepicker
         [date]="getDueDate()"
         [options]="datetimepicker_options"
         style="opacity: 0; maxlength: 4; height: 30px; width: 100px;"
         (onChange)="dateToChange($event)"
         />
```

Yet this does not open the associated calendar of the a2e-datetimepicker.

I have hunted high and low attempting to access the a2e-datetimepicker directly without success.  Do you have an idea how to do this?  Or why does the dispatchEvent or even a nativeElement.click() not reach the a2e-datetimepicker?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that what I needed here was to call focus(). Like so:

```
public showDate() {
   this.datetimepickerElement.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Also I learned how to access the underlying directive like this:

```
  import { DateTimePickerDirective } from '../../../../../node_modules/ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker/dist/datetimepicker.directive';

  @ViewChild(DateTimePickerDirective) datetimempickerDirective;
```

And then can do:

```
    this.datetimempickerDirective.dpElement[0].focus();
```

but this does the same in this case to the easier

```
   this.datetimepickerElement.nativeElement.focus();
```

This will hopefully help somelse that is still learning angular2.